# How to promote an iPhone app (productivity / goal-setting)

Tags: iphone, applications

I've made an iPhone application that is a goal-setting workshop (that is - it doesn't just track goals - it helps users to decide upon them). That is quite a novel approach I think.

There is a New Year approaching so there will be many articles on New Year's resolutions (and in some cases - goal setting applications). I would like to let journalists know about my app.

I have already prepared a press release package and sent it to the app review sites. What more can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Press packages are a start but the press gets tons of those. There's no way of knowing, but you could be one of several developers that sent a press kit for a similar application.

You should definitely have a website for the product to promote it in the way you feel is appropriate.

Also, going to developer, mobile, and computer conferences and meeting with Apple, relevant press folks, and interested users is a good way to get attention, just be sure to have business cards and promo codes handy for when you meet people and want to show them your app.

There are many articles and books that cover this aspect of iPhone development including strategies on working with the App Store as well, most going beyond the scope of the Q&A format of this site.